# array of struct C scanf with float

Tags: c, struct

hello im trying to work with a struct of students but everytime i ask the input of grade the program stop running and i dont know why. im using Turbo C++ 4.0. if i use grades as int the program doesnt stop but when i use them as float the program stop running. please any help heres the code:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define num 2
struct student {
  char name[50];
  float cal1;
  float cal2;
  float prom;
} est[num];

int main () {
  int i=0;
  clrscr();
  for(i=0;i<=num;i++) {
    printf("\nName of student[%d]:",i);
    scanf("%s",&est[i].name);
    printf("\nGrade #1 [%d]:",i);
    scanf("%f",&est[i].cal1);
    printf("\nGrade #2 [%d]:",i);
    scanf("%f",&est[i].cal2);
  }

  for(i=0;i<=num;i++) {
    printf("\nStudent [%d]:",i);
    printf("\nName: ");
    printf("%s",est[i].name);
    printf("\nGrade #1: ");
    printf("%f",est[i].cal1);
    printf("\nGrade #2: ");
    printf("%f",est[i].cal2);
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be more Specific. What is the error you've got ?

Comment: use different IDE/compiler it'll work fine.

Comment: the program doesnt ask for the float grades. if i use them as int it works fine but i need to use them as float

Comment: the program works fine here. get a different compiler.

Comment: If the name contain spaces, `scanf("%s",&est[i].name);` change to `scanf(" %49[^\n]", est[i].name);`

Comment: I am wondering whether you are attempting to input with whitespace. Please post sample input you are using to test your program.

Comment: Name of student [0]
Steve  

the program just ask the name and stop running.

Comment: always check the returned value from scanf() to assure the operation was successful.  when using '%s', always include a length modifier, so the input buffer is not overrun.   do these things for all scanf() calls.  when using '%s' always use ' %s' (note leading space) so leading white space is skipped over

Comment: @user3629249 `"%s"` also leading white space is skipped.

Comment: @Dave0124 `printf("\nName of student[%d]:",i);` chage to `printf("\nName of student[%d]:\n",i);` (`\n` add last) or  try add `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: @mescalinum, the code does not work 'fine'.  It inputs a third entry into the 'est[]' array, where a third entry is beyond the bounds of the array, resulting in undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @user3629249: that has been already pointed out by user3121023, and apart from that, the program runs as expected.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY.  %s' does not skip leading white space.  quote from: <http://www.tenouk.com/clabworksheet/labworksheet6.html> , which is just one of many references that say the same thing.  " String, up to first white-space character (space, tab or newline). "  I.E. it stops reading at the first white space character, and when a newline is the first character in stdin, nothing is read

Comment: @user3629249 see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/R2hJOx) `NAME` has leading white space. OUTPUT doesn't include space.

Comment: @user3629249 `"%s"` does not skip leading white space" is **incorrect**.  The C spec (not some derived  reference - which is not accessible): "Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier." C11 §7.21.6.2 8. Perhaps you are confusing leading whitespace with trailing whitespace.  After skipping leading whitespace `"%s"` does : "Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.". C11 §7.21.6.2 12

Comment: thanks everyone for the help. i read the question user3121023 suggested and it fixed my problem with:

    extern unsigned _floatconvert;
    #pragma extref _floatconvert

Answer (score 2):

You define:

```
#define num 2
struct student { … } est[num];
```

and you loop on:

```
for (i = 0; i <= num; i++)
{
    …scanning code…
}
```

This is a buffer overflow.  It attempts to read 3 students worth of data, with the third student's data going into the space after the space allocated for `est`.  This is a buffer overflow and leads to undefined behaviour; anything can happen and it is OK.

In C, get used to using the idiomatic `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
```

In the code that reads data, you need to check that the `scanf()` calls succeed:

```
printf("\nName of student[%d]:",i);
if (scanf("%s", est[i].name) != 1)  // Note no & for strings
    …handle error…
printf("\nGrade #1 [%d]:",i);
if (scanf("%f", &est[i].cal1) != 1)
    …handle error…
printf("\nGrade #2 [%d]:",i);
if (scanf("%f", &est[i].cal2) != 1)
    …handle error…
```

The printing loop should not attempt to print more entries than were actually read, which might be less than `num` if there was an error.  Obviously, it needs to be in the idiomatic form too, but you should really be using:

```
int j;
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

or something similar so if only 1 entry was read, you only print that one entry.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of the code that 
cleanly compiles, links, runs

I did not use conio.h as it is non-standard 
(and not available on my machine)

*this code still needs the error checking for returned value from scanf added*

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // system()

#define num (2)

struct student 
{
    char name[50];
    float cal1;
    float cal2;
    float prom;  // only one ';'
};

// separated definition, above, from declaration, below

struct student est[num];

int main () 
{
    int i=0;
    system( "cls" );
    //clrscr();

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)  // note correction to for statement
    {
        printf("\nName of student[%d]:",i);
        scanf(" %49s", est[i].name); // note correction to format string
                                     // and using array 
                                     // as degraded into pointer
                                     // otherwise 
                                     // unknown where trying to place data
            // added vertical spacing for readability
        printf("\nGrade #1 [%d]:",i);
        scanf("%f", &est[i].cal1);
            // added vertical spacing for readability
        printf("\nGrade #2 [%d]:",i);
        scanf("%f", &est[i].cal2);
    }

    for(i=0;i<num;i++) // note correction to 'for' statement
    {
        printf("\nStudent [%d]:",i);
        printf("\nName: ");
        printf("%s",est[i].name);
        printf("\nGrade #1: ");
        printf("%f",est[i].cal1);
        printf("\nGrade #2: ");
        printf("%f",est[i].cal2);
    }

    getchar(); // this will input the final newline, so will exit immediately
    //getch();
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```